# How to toggle hidden by default without any animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I using a bootstrap tree menu

the code will be hidden all sub_menu default

but, `onload` page will be run a animation to close.

How to without it?

JS here

```
$('.tree-toggle').click(function () {   
  $(this).parent().children('ul.tree').toggle(200);
});
$(function(){
  $('.tree-toggle').parent().children('ul.tree').toggle(200);
})
```

All code in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/kanhasahu/pen/rewvEo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the duration from the one that runs on page load:

```
$('.tree-toggle').click(function () {   
  $(this).parent().children('ul.tree').toggle(200);
});
$(function(){
  $('.tree-toggle').parent().children('ul.tree').toggle();
})
```

As mentioned in the documentation for [Toggle](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display):

> With no parameters, the .toggle() method simply toggles the visibility of elements:

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [delay parameter to `0`(or ignore)](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-duration-complete) to avoid the animation.

```
$(function() {
  $(".tree-toggle")
    .parent()
    .children("ul.tree")
    .toggle(0);
});
```

```js
$(".tree-toggle").click(function() {
  $(this)
    .parent()
    .children("ul.tree")
    .toggle(300);
});
$(function() {
  $(".tree-toggle")
    .parent()
    .children("ul.tree")
    .toggle(0);
});
```

```css
.no-padding {
  padding: 0px;
}

.glyphicon-icon-rpad .glyphicon,
.glyphicon-icon-rpad .glyphicon.m8,
.fa-icon-rpad .fa,
.fa-icon-rpad .fa.m8 {
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.glyphicon-icon-lpad .glyphicon,
.glyphicon-icon-lpad .glyphicon.m8,
.fa-icon-lpad .fa,
.fa-icon-lpad .fa.m8 {
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.glyphicon-icon-rpad .glyphicon.m5,
.fa-icon-rpad .fa.m5 {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.glyphicon-icon-lpad .glyphicon.m5,
.fa-icon-lpad .fa.m5 {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.glyphicon-icon-rpad .glyphicon.m12,
.fa-icon-rpad .fa.m12 {
  padding-right: 12px;
}

.glyphicon-icon-lpad .glyphicon.m12,
.fa-icon-lpad .fa.m12 {
  padding-left: 12px;
}

.glyphicon-icon-rpad .glyphicon.m15,
.fa-icon-rpad .fa.m15 {
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.glyphicon-icon-lpad .glyphicon.m15,
.fa-icon-lpad .fa.m15 {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

ul.nav-menu-list-style .nav-header .menu-collapsible-icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  top: 16px;
  font-size: 9px;
}

ul.nav-menu-list-style {
  margin: 0;
}

ul.nav-menu-list-style .nav-header {
  border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 42px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

ul.nav-menu-list-style>li {
  position: relative;
}

ul.nav-menu-list-style>li a {
  border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 32px;
}

ul.nav-menu-list-style>li:first-child a {}

ul.nav-menu-list-style {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

ul.nav-menu-list-style li .badge,
ul.nav-menu-list-style li .pull-right,
ul.nav-menu-list-style li span.badge,
ul.nav-menu-list-style li label.badge {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

ul.bullets {
  list-style: inside disc
}

ul.numerics {
  list-style: inside decimal
}

.ul.kas-icon-aero {}

ul.kas-icon-aero li a:before {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-size: 9px;
  content: "\e258";
  padding-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Bootstrap Tree Menu Example</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="well no-padding">
        <div>
          <ul class="nav nav-list nav-menu-list-style">
            <li><label class="tree-toggle nav-header glyphicon-icon-rpad"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close m5"></span>Bootstrap
                            <span class="menu-collapsible-icon glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></label>
              <ul class="nav nav-list tree bullets">
                <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CSS <span class="badge">42</span></a></li>
                <li><label class="tree-toggle nav-header">Buttons</label>
                  <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                    <li><a href="#">Colors</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sizes</a></li>
                    <li><label class="tree-toggle nav-header">Forms</label>
                      <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                        <li><a href="#">Horizontal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Vertical</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><label class="tree-toggle nav-header">Responsive</label>
              <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                <li><label class="tree-toggle nav-header">Media Queries</label>
                  <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                    <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Images</a></li>
                    <li><label class="tree-toggle nav-header">Mobile Devices</label>
                      <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                        <li><a href="#">iPhone</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Samsung</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><label class="tree-toggle nav-header">Coding</label>
                  <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
                    <li><label class="tree-toggle nav-header">HTML DOM</label>
                      <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
                        <li><a href="#">DOM Elements</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Recursive</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```